# How to traverse on only a cycle in a graph?

Tags: graphs

I'm attempting ch23 in CLRS on MSTs, here's a question:

> Given a graph G and a minimum spanning tree T , suppose that we decrease the weight of one of the edges not in T . Give an algorithm for finding the minimum spanning tree in the modified graph.

A solution I found was to add this new changed edge in `T`, then exactly one simple cycle is created in T, traverse this cycle and delete the max-weight edge in this cycle, *voila*, the new updated MST is found!

My question is, how do I **only** traverse nodes on this simple-cycle? Since DFS/BFS traversals might go out of the cycle if I, say, start the traversal in `T` from one endpoint of this newly added edge in `T`.

One solution I could think of was to find the `biconnected components` in `T` after adding the new edge. Only one `BCC` will be found, which is this newly formed simple-cycle, then I can put in a special condition in my DFS code saying to only traverse edges/nodes in this BCC, and once a back-edge is found, stop the traversal.

Edit: graph G is connected and undirected btw